# How to initiate an action to `component` from `Router`

Tags: validation, ember.js, ember-components

In my page, the `router` taking care of page transition. but before i go for next page, I would like to validate the `form` fields. for that I use the `cp-validation` addon.

But when the next button clicked, I would like to ask my child component to do the validation and send back the result to `router`. how to do this?

I tried to validate the model within `router` but not works. if my try is not correct way please let me know the correct approach to handle this scenario.

my router bhs:

```
    <div class="balanceEmi rdc-scroll-content has-subheader rdc-view">
        {{cs2i-select-tenure selectedCreditCard=model}}//my component 
//which requie to know the form validation
    </div>

<div class="rdc-view___footer rdc-view___footer---stickey">
    {{rdc-button default="CANCEL" type="secondary" action="redirect"}}
    {{#if enableNext}}
        {{rdc-button default="NEXT" type="primary" action="goToNext"}}
    {{else}}
            {{rdc-button default="NEXT" type="primary" disabled="true"}}
    {{/if}} 
    <div class="formValidateBeforeNextBtn" {{action 'formValidateBeforeNext'}}>//let this actin call my component to do the validaiton else le tme know the correct way
        <!-- empty for validation button-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend registering the validate component to a factory, then you can call this from wherever you are in your application like a router.

Read the Ember.js docs [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/applications/dependency-injection/)

Comment: But how it consider the current models as target?